# How to implement a random number generator that is not random?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, random

I need a random number generator that generates various number between n and m, but no with a equal probability. I want to set a value x between n and m where the possibility is the highest:

[image]

Is there an easy way to do that using the Random class? The likelihood should have the form of a binominal distribution or something similar (it is not important that its an exact binominal distributon, rough approximations are also ok)

### EDIT

Maybe I have to clarify: I'm not looking for a binominal or gaussian distribution but also for something like this:
[image]

I want to to define the value x where the highest likelihood should be.

### EDIT

Unfortunately the previously accepted answer [does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5281672/329637) how i suspected. So I'm still looking for an answer!

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218060/random-gaussian-variables

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to generate Poisson and binomial random numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241555/algorithm-to-generate-poisson-and-binomial-random-numbers)

Comment: `double random() { return 17; }` - responding to your subject only.

This `(17, 17, 17, ...)` is actually called a `"Hebrew University Random Sequence"`. Every teacher in HUJI says at least once a week "let's take any number. Say... 17"

:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Box-Muller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) transform to generate a sequence of psuedorandom normally distributed numbers from a sequence of numbers uniformally distributed between 0 and 1.

[image: Box-Muller transform]

Comment: Note that this methods generates *two* gaussian distributed numbers from to uniformly distributed numbers. So it's easy to make it about twice as fast compared to just generating one as you posted.

Answer (score 5):

Java SDK  has good implementation Random.nextGaussian (taken from http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian())

I hope it is rather clear how to parse from java source to c#

```
synchronized public double nextGaussian() {
    if (haveNextNextGaussian) {
            haveNextNextGaussian = false;
            return nextNextGaussian;
    } else {
            double v1, v2, s;
            do { 
                    v1 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
                    v2 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
                    s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
            } while (s >= 1 || s == 0);
            double multiplier = Math.sqrt(-2 * Math.log(s)/s);
            nextNextGaussian = v2 * multiplier;
            haveNextNextGaussian = true;
            return v1 * multiplier;
    }
 }
```

**UPDATE:** How I've made shift of median:

```
public static float gaussianInRange(float from, float mean, float to)
{
    if( !(from < mean && mean < to) )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(MessageFormat.format("RandomRange.gaussianInRange({0}, {1}, {2})", from, mean, to));

    int p = _staticRndGen.nextInt(100);
    float retval;
    if (p < (mean*Math.abs(from - to)))
    {
        double interval1 = (_staticRndGen.nextGaussian() * (mean - from));
        retval = from + (float) (interval1);
    }
    else
    {
        double interval2 = (_staticRndGen.nextGaussian() * (to - mean));
        retval = mean + (float) (interval2);
    }
    while (retval < from || retval > to)
    {
        if (retval < from)
            retval = (from - retval) + from;
        if (retval > to)
            retval = to - (retval - to);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Yes that would be clear. But how can I now set the most likelihood to my value?

Comment: @Roflcoptr - per SDK return value of nextGaussian is a value around 0.0 with deviation 1.0 (so result is in range(-1;1)). So just append +2 to get values in range (1..3)

Comment: @Dewfy: yes I understand this, but then the highest likelihood is at 0 respectively 1.5. But what if the highest likelihood should be close to 3?

Comment: @Roflcoptr - well, actually I had the same problem - make shift relative median, so look my update in answer.

Comment: @Dewfy Thanks a lot that is exactly the whole method I'm looking for!

Comment: @Dewfy: Have you tested you're solution? I implemented it an tested it with n=10'000 and gaussianInRange(0, 0.2, 1) and the average result is always slightely above 0.4.

Answer (score 1):

You need a generator working on a "Normal Distribution". Have a look here:
http://www.csharpcity.com/reusable-code/random-number-generators/

Answer (score 0):

smth relatively simple.
You can generate 2 random numbers:
1st defines how close to x  the 2nd random number would be.

You can use any breakpoint/function levels you like.