# What is the difference between the parameters and the shape of a Numpy Binomial Distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am working on a project doing some Bayseian Statistics in Python and am using the Numpy Random Binomial function. However while putting in the keyword arguments/parameters I am a bit confused with some of the basic theory behind this. My set up is the following:

```
trial = np.random.binomial(n, .10, 1)
```

(Where n = 1000)

**Problem:** Say you flip a biased coin (p = .10).

**Question:** Is there a difference between 1000 tosses with .10 probability done once or 1 toss with .10 probably done 1000 times? Which is preferable? Is one more computationally efficient than the other?

ie. what is, if there is one, the difference between:

```
np.random.binomial(1000, .10, 1)
```

and

```
np.random.binomial(1, .10, 1000)
```

Or, phrased a different way, what is the difference between the parameters of a distribution and the shape?

I have read the Numpy Binomial Docs found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html)

If someone could explain the theory or basic intuition behind this that would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering this example

```
In [51]: for i in range(10): print (np.random.binomial(10, 0.3))
2
3
5
2
4
2
5
3
1
2
```

It is equvilant to say: if p=0.3, and n=10; meaning the biased coin is baised (0.3 of chance of getting head) and the number of trials is 10, how many times out of 10 I will get head?  Of course it is not going to be exactly 3 all the time, (and in fact you may even 10 heads out of 10 tosses, albeit at very small probability), as it is demonstrated here by running it in a loop for 10 times.

However in numpy we often will not run thing in a loop. If we want to generate 10 such numbers, we can supply an additional size parameter to the call

```
In [53]: np.random.binomial(10, 0.3, size=10)
Out[53]: array([3, 5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4])
```

Comment: In `np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.10, size=1000)`, yes it is an array of 1000 elements of 0 and 1, but this is due to `n=1`.  Since there is only 1 toss, it would has to either 1 or 0.  In `np.random.binomial(n=1000, p=.10, size=1)`, the result is an array of 1 element: try 1000 timer and the count of the times of successes.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

When the outcome of a single random trial is a "success" with probability p, we call that a Bernoulli trial with parameter p, a.k.a. a Bernoulli(p).  The binomial distribution evaluates the probability of getting a particular number of "successes" if we run n independent Bernoulli trials with the same p.  We call that a binomial distribution with parameters n and p, a.k.a. a binomial(n, p). By convention, Bernoulli successes are encoded as a 1, and failures as a 0.  Consequently, a Bernoulli(p) and a binomial(1, p) are the same thing.

If we're generating values from a binomial(n, p) the outcome is a count of how many successes were observed in a realization of n trials. The number of successes is thus the sum of n Bernoulli results.

Now to NumPy.  Invoking `np.random.binomial(1000, .10, 1)` generates one realization of a binomial with n = 1000 and p = 0.1.  Using `np.random.binomial(1, .10, 1000)` generates 1000 realizations of a binomial with n = 1 and p = 0.1, i.e., 1000 Bernoulli(0.1)'s.  These are *not* the same thing, but if you sum the Bernoulli values using `sum(np.random.binomial(1, .10, 1000))` the result will have the same distribution as `np.random.binomial(1000, .10, 1)`.

Is one of them better than the other?  While they are interchangeable from a distributional perspective, there are [more efficient computational methods to generate binomials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23574723/2166798) than just generating n Bernoullis and summing them.  Assuming the implementers of NumPy are competent, you're probably better off using `np.random.binomial(1000, .10, 1)`.