# Java: Probability distribution support

Tags: java, math, statistics

I need to implement random sampling from a number of common probability distributions (normal, binomial, gamma, ...) in my java program. I found [Random.nextGaussian()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian()) and was just wondering if there's any other built in support for distributions other than normal? Or are my only options third party library or DIY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’d be looking at java.lang.math, and from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html):

> The class Math contains methods for performing basic numeric
>   operations such as the elementary exponential, logarithm, square root,
>   and trigonometric functions.

So in short no. For distributions other than Gaussian you’re going to have to look elsewhere.

In terms of third party libraries, [Apache Commons (AbstractRealDistribution)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/AbstractRealDistribution.html) is probably your best bet. But I’ve also had success with [Colt](https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/).

As for DIY, a simple google search should do it, e.g. [Gamma](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ReturnasamplefromtheGammaPoissionGaussiandistributionwithparameterIA.htm), [Binomial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241555/algorithm-to-generate-poisson-and-binomial-random-numbers)